# How do I run a command a certain number of times as specified by user input?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I want to get input as integer from user on batch file console and run as this input times.

So if i input 10 in beginning.

`start test.exe` must run 10 times.

how can i write this in batch file?

Comment: Have you heard of `for /L`? type `for /?` in a command prompt window and read the appearing help text carefully...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a FOR /L command.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /p num=How many times:
FOR /L %%I IN (1,1,%num%) DO START "My Title" "test.exe"
```